# Seaborn.lineplot() SEM error bars not working

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have the following code. I want to plot error bars representing the standard error of the mean on the graphs below. However, when I run the code, I get the error: 'Line2D' object has no property 'errorbar'

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2,figsize=(15, 15))
fig.tight_layout(pad=6)

newerdf=newdf.copy()
bins = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
names = ['<2', '2-4', '4-6', '6-8', '8+']
d = dict(enumerate(names, 1))
newerdf['caffeinatedbeveragesperdayrange'] = np.digitize(newerdf['caffeinatedbeveragesperday'], bins)
newerdf['caffeinatedbeveragesperdayrange'] = newerdf['caffeinatedbeveragesperdayrange'].map(d)
Graph1 = sns.lineplot(data=newerdf,x="caffeinatedbeveragesperdayrange", y="distance",err_style='bars',errorbar ='se',ax=axes[0])
Graph2 = sns.lineplot(data=newerdf,x="caffeinatedbeveragesperdayrange", y="duration",err_style='bars',errorbar ='se',ax=axes[1])
Graph1.set_xlabel( "Number of caffeinated beverages per day",labelpad = 10,weight='bold')
Graph2.set_xlabel( "Number of caffeinated beverages per day",labelpad = 10,weight='bold')
Graph1.set_ylabel("Wayfinding Distance",labelpad = 10,weight='bold')
Graph2.set_ylabel("Wayfinding Duration",labelpad = 10,weight='bold')
```

[image]

I would be so grateful a helping hand!

The first 6 rows of the `newerdf['caffeinatedbeveragesperdayrange'],newerdf['distance'] and newerdf['duration']` dataframes:

```
caffeinatedbeveragesperdayrange
10  <2
13  4-6
17  2-4
19  <2
21  <2
22  <2

distance
10  48.146090
13  98.877301
17  66.670310
19  95.764316
21  78.737108
22  48.404197

    duration
10  40.976006
13  90.093298
17  88.349603
19  82.737323
21  72.579054
22  40.059987
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the latest seaborn version? Note that, when reporting an error, it often helps to copy the full error trace to the post (as text).

Comment: '0.11.2' - seems to be an older version. I will try to install the latest version. Thanks so much for your help - I will let you know if that changes things!

Comment: @JohanC - can I check that entering 'conda install seaborn=0.12' in the terminal will update sns to the latest version?

Comment: I deleted the tag of visa studio code for you. This problem has nothing to do with him. Wrong tags will bring inconvenience to engineers :)

Answer (score 3):

The seaborn version `0.11` don't have this feature.

You should upgrade your seaborn at least to version `0.12.x` in your environment with the command:

```bash
pip install --upgrade seaborn
```